# Is it proper to build a site supporting blog visitors in WordPress?

Tags: user-roles

I am quite new to WordPress and PHP. I am currently working on a website and I finally come down to WordPress. I guess I might be able to accomplish my work on top of WordPress but I am not sure. I want to hear you opinion.

My requirements:

1. Users can register a blog in our site and publish their pages.
2. Users can embed images, audios and videos in their pages.
3. Users can custom the theme of their blogs.
4. Users can create/delete a list of visitors for their blog. Visitors should have basic infomation such as name, email and auto-generated passcode. (For example, a blog owner might want someone to enter a passcode to view a certain page of his blog)
5. Users can create polls in their pages. (A question and a list of answers)
6. Blog visitors can respond to a blog by comments or by answering the owner's questions.
7. Users (blog owner) can do statistics based on visitors' response. (For example, who respond to which questions)

I think 1, 2, 3 are trivial in WordPress, but not sure if 4, 5, 6, 7 are proper to implement in WordPress, or if there are better options. (open source projects which I can build on, PHP/Java are both OK)

My question is:

1. Am I in the correct way to build my site on top of WordPress?
2. It is convenient to implement functions of 4, 5, 6, 7 in WordPress?
3. Could you point me some WordPress examlpes already implemented 4, 5, 6, 7?

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you need to use the [WordPress Network](http://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network) feature

Documentation of interest:

- [Don't Use WordPress Multisite](http://halfelf.org/2011/dont-use-wordpress-multisite/)
- [Multisite Rationale](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1h1CejwUCKU9SNLtTwHxxZKfGjTWtUkpiMM4wyZdQS8s/edit?hl=en_US)
- [WordPress Multisite 101](http://halfelf.org/ebooks/wordpress-multisite-101/)
- [WordPress Multisite 110](http://halfelf.org/ebooks/wordpress-multisite-110/)

EDIT: 
Some features of Wordpress Multisite based on my investigation:

1 Users can register a blog in your site and publish their pages.

2 Users can embed images, audios and videos in their pages.

3 Users can customize the theme of their blogs.

4 Users can create polls in their pages. (A question and a list of answers)

5 Blog visitors can respond to a blog by comments or by answering the owner's questions.

6 Users can create/delete a list of visitors for their blog. Visitors should have basic infomation such as name, email and auto-generated passcode. (For example, a blog owner might want someone to enter a passcode to view a certain page of his blog)

To get started and to learn more, go [HERE](http://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network)

Also, check out [BuddyPress, a WordPress plugin that will allow you to build your own Social Network](http://bnuddypress.org)

Comment: I agree with you ... but you could expand your answer addressing why WordPress network is best and just name drop a few plugins :)

Comment: Ive added more to my answer. You'll have to read documentation to get started.

Comment: It is very kind of you Aliyah, I think I could build me site on top of WordPress!